# How can i set language from SQLServerDataSource using Spring data

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-data

Good I have the need to make certain queries to the database sql server working with dates, I am presented with the inconvenience that as language in the installation of sql server is in English therefore the results are defined in that language for example to perform the consult with the following function `DATENAME (WEEKDAY, date)` the result would be for example Tuesday, as far as my need is to show it in Spanish.
A solution that I have applied is to do this from the application, obtaining the date and perform the conversion from the application.

But I would like to know if it is possible to make this configuration globally from the application through the configuration parameters of the DataSource?

Configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.company.app.repository" })
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.company.app.repository" })
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @EnableJpaAuditing
    @PropertySource("classpath:/db.properties")

public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    //private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ApplicationConfig.class); 


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

    //  OracleDataSource oracleDS = null;
        SQLServerDataSource dataSource = null;

        //  oracleDS = new OracleDataSource();
        dataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL(environment.getProperty("cendb.url"));//
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getProperty("cendb.user"));//
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("cendb.password"));

        return dataSource;

    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.company.app.model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> createAuditorProvider() {
        return new CustomAuditorAware();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditingEntityListener createAuditingListener() {
        return new AuditingEntityListener();
    }
```

Comment: You can change the language of the Login on the SQL Server; the language of a login does not need to be the same as the Server's, and you can have different login's with different languages on the same server. If you set the language of the login to Spanish, does the issue not resolve itself? [ALTER LOGIN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me